# Uncaught ReferenceError: command is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to do a command handler on a discord bot (with discord.js) but when I start the bot I get an error:

> ReferenceError: command is not defined

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDKIo.png)

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const intents = new discord.Intents();
const client = new discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });

const fs = require('fs');
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');

client.commands = new discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./comandos').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./comandos/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

let cmd = client.commands.find((c) => c.name === command || c.alias && c.alias.includes(command));
if(!cmd){
    cmd.execute(client, message, args);
} else {
    if(!cmd){
        return;
    }
}

const config = require('./config.js');
const prefix = config.prefix;

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That must be in a `messageCreate` event:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  const [ command, ...args ] = message.content.split(/ +/g);
  let cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.commands.find((c) => c.alias?.includes(command));
  if (cmd) { //you also made a mistake here, remove the "!"
    cmd.execute(client, message, args);
  }
})
```

Comment: I would also point out the redundancy with the `else` statement checking for `!cmd`

Comment: Solved! thanks, but I'm still having problems, can you help me with these?

        cmd.execute(client, message, args);
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')

Comment: Did you remove the `!` for the `if (!cmd)`? Also if this answer helped, consider giving it a checkmark and/or upvote

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're using `const` to define `command` inside the loop. You need to replace it with var and it should work fine:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const intents = new discord.Intents();
const client = new discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });

const fs = require('fs');
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');

client.commands = new discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./comandos').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    var command = require(`./comandos/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

let cmd = client.commands.find((c) => c.name === command || c.alias && c.alias.includes(command));
if(!cmd){
    cmd.execute(client, message, args);
} else {
    if(!cmd){
        return;
    }
}

const config = require('./config.js');
const prefix = config.prefix;

client.login(config.token);
```

*(using "let" won't work either because it is not in the global scope).*

Comment: This won't fix the code - they will now just get `message` is not defined

Comment: @MrMythical I guess I haven't noticed the problem. Hopefully the OP will take both answers and it'll work

Comment: Also, using `var` is now considered bad practice (or so I've heard) and you should use `let` and `const` now

Comment: @MrMythical I've never heard of that. But `var` is in the global scope so it can solve the problem

Comment: `command` will *always* be the last loaded command because it's after the `for` loop meaning your answer will not work properly, while mine will

Comment: As @MrMythical mentioned, this won't work.